# Rails error 500, "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

After three evenings on this problem and reading all the posts about this, I have to ask this question finally!

I want to deploy the most simple Rails app to Heroku:

```bash
rails new test_appli
cd test_appli
git init
git add .
git  commit -m "initial commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

Everything's OK, the application works well on Heroku. After that, I'll create a SQLite3 database:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
rake db:migrate
```

Everything's OK on the local machine. I can see `localhost:3000/users` well. Then I want to put the DB on Heroku. First I modify my Gemfile:

```ruby
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Then I send the whole thing to Heroku:

```bash
git init
git add .
git  commit -m "with Database"
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Then there are no errors in the batch, everything is OK, the DB is sent, but the page `heroku.com/users` gives the error

> Rails 500, "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

I don't know more what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: have you checked your logfile with `heroku logs` from the terminal?

Comment: sure, it didn't say nothing... the answer is below. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you're trying to deploy a Rails 3.1 application to the bamboo stack (heroku create defaults to the 1.9.2 bamboo stack and doesn't run Rails 3.1 out of the box.). The Cedar stack is much better suited to Rails 3.1 sites -

try

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

when creating your application on Heroku and repush it up. Also note your rake command on Heroku will become

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

Do:

heroku run rake db:schema:load

I had the same issue. It works for me after git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the git init in the second set of commands - you only need to initialise your Git repo once.

Other than that this looks fine - are you seeing any errors anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was the rails version with the stack. With rails 3, only stack cedar!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use the `pg` gem in your production group, but the `sqlite3` gem in your development group?  Seems to me that your problem is likely due to the fact that you're developing with a different database then you're using in the production environment.  If I were you, I would stick to one, which would make it much easier to debug.

If you really want/need to get the application running ASAP, then just run it in production with sqlite...  Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Also, a quick way to figure out what the error is would be to run `heroku logs` from the unix console.

Comment: Hi, Heroku can't run sqlite3 but transform the DB in pg. You have to make it like that in the gemfile.
The problem was the rails version with the stack. With rails 3, only stack cedar!

Comment: Actually, Heroku can run sqlite3.  I have rails3 application running on Heroku which is using sqlite3.  We are using this stack: bamboo-ree-1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Rails?
Can you try creating the application running on the Cedar stack?

```
heroku create myapp --stack cedar
```

Given the application is running on cedar you need to modify the commands a bit, for example:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

In any case you really need to checkout your logs, because your problem might not even be database related, but assets related.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the heroku shared 5mb database instance added?
When you create your heroku app (on cedar) it doesn't necessarily create the database automatically.

```
airlift:projects  $ heroku create --stack cedar testapp9
Creating testapp9... done, stack is cedar
http://testapp9.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:testapp9.git

airlift:projects  $ heroku addons --app testapp9 
logging:basic
releases:basic
```

When you view your heroku config, you get nothing:

> heroku config

```
airlift:projects  $ heroku config --app testapp9
airlift:projects  $
```

To add a database:

> heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb

```
airlift:projects  $ heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb --app testapp9
-----> Adding shared-database:5mb to testapp9... done, v3 (free)
airlift:projects  $ heroku config
No app specified.
Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
airlift:projects  $ heroku config --app testapp9
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://blah:blah@blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com/blah
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://blah:blah@blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com/blah
airlift:projects  $
```

Then you should be able migrate your db.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your Help. Actually, as John Beynon said, I only had to push it to a cedar stack because of the rails version. It works like that! But I really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey @redronin thanks for helping me find a way to connect to my postgres database on Heroku, however as a newbie to Heroku and postgresql I had to reverse engineer what "blah" was. So I figure I would break it down to help others as you helped me.

postgres://[user]:[password]@[servername].compute-1.amazonaws.com/[database]